# Python Pong Game not increasing point after 1

Tags: python, pong

So I've tried to make a Pong game in Python with turtle, everything is working except one thing. When the player_score reach 1 point its not increasing anymore. And an annoying thing, does anybody know why is the ball slow down when i move the racket?

Here is my code:

**I think this part of the code is okay.**

```
from turtle import *

# Creating screen
court = Screen()
court.title("Bricket Pong v 0.2")
court.setup(width=800, height=600)
court.bgcolor('black')
court.tracer(0)

# Creating ball
ball = Turtle()
ball.shape("circle")
ball.color("green")
ball.penup()
ball.setpos(0, 0)

# Creating ball movement speed
def init():
    global ball, want_continue
    ball.step_x = 0.5
    ball.step_y = 0.5
    ball.setpos(0, 0)
    want_continue = True


def on_quit():
    global want_continue
    want_continue = False


court.onkey(on_quit, "q")
court.listen()

# Creating point screen
point = Turtle()
point.speed(0)
point.color('blue')
point.penup()
point.hideturtle()
point.goto(0,260)
point.write("Player: 0 ",align="center",font=('Monaco',24,"normal"))


racket = Turtle()
racket.hideturtle()
racket.shape("square")
racket.color("white")
racket.penup()
racket.goto(0, -285)
racket.shapesize(1, 3)
racket.showturtle()

# Creating arrows to move the racket
def racket_left():
    x =racket.xcor()
    x = x - 15
    racket.setx(x)


def racket_right():
    x = racket.xcor()
    x = x + 15
    racket.setx(x)

court.listen()

court.onkeypress(racket_left, "Left")
court.onkeypress(racket_right, "Right")
```

**The problem is must be here in move_ball def.**

```
# Creating borders to the ball
def move_ball():
    global ball
    player_score = 0
    if ball.xcor() > 390 or ball.xcor() < -390:
        ball.step_x *= -1

    if ball.ycor() > 290:
        ball.step_y *= -1

    if ball.ycor() < -290:
        ball.setpos(0, 0)
        ball.step_y *= -1
        player_score= 0
        point.clear()
        point.write("Player: {} ".format(player_score), align="center", font=('Monaco', 24, "normal"))


    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.step_x)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.step_y)

#Racket ball border
    if (ball.ycor() < - 265) and ball.ycor() > - 275 \
            and (racket.xcor() + 30 > ball.xcor() > racket.xcor() - 30) :
        ball.step_y = ball.step_y * -1
        player_score += 1 
        point.clear()
        point.write("Player: {}".format(player_score),align="center",font=('Monaco',24,"normal"))

def run():
    global ball, want_continue
    while want_continue:
        move_ball()
        court.update()





#
init()
run()

court.bye()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're continually setting the player_score to zero, at the top of the `move_ball()` function (so, every cycle through the `while` loop in `run()`) -- you'll have to initialize it somewhere else and increment it without resetting it.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem you can define e.g `score_a = 0` and `score_b = 0` before wherever the *collision function* is and then update the score every time ball collides.
And you can display the score with *formatted strings* as `print(f"Player A: {score_a}    Player B: {score_b}")` or `print("Player A: {}    Player B: {}".format)`

The problem of ball slowing down on collision is due to the way of code. The movement of the ball is done by adding some int value to ball's current (x,y) coords. This value is added every time the screen updates. The loop updates the position as many times as it can in one frame. But due to varying CPU  speed every second the ball seems to move inconsistently.

To get a more consistent behavior you could add a long enough pause into your loop to offset the variability of the computing times and to avoid drawing useless frames. You can do this using `time`

```
import time

# Initialization
...

while True:
   time.sleep(1 / 60)

   # The rest of your game logic
   ...
```

Comment: This will help in debugging but is not the answer for the question.

Comment: The user is having issues with displaying player scores and this an easy way to get it done